# Is it possible to make RFID tag unwritable?

Tags: hardware, rfid

Is it possible to make an RFID tag that is unwritable after initial setup using only software (e.i. only using stock firmware)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can permalock the tags. Meaning you can put the tags on readonly mode.

Comment: Is it possible for someone to break this? If so how?